# NoMethodError - undefined method `key?' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options:0x00007fe03ee04608>:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, software-distribution

When I start server with `rails s` then I am getting following error.

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: Looks like `key?` is not the method which can be called on that object. You might want to change it to hash. Try `options.to_h.key?(k)`

Comment: Please post actual code snippets in your question rather than images of code. Images can't be searched and make it difficult to cut-and-paste when try to reproduce someone's example.

Comment: Sorry, I totally blanked in my answer that the code you posted isn't yours (it's been a long day). Looks like there might be an issue with how you are configuring your redis cache. Can you edit your question to include your initializers where you configure the session store?

Answer (score 1):

In your case `options` is an `ActionDispatch::Request::Session::Options` object, not a `Hash`. You can call `.to_hash` on it to convert it to a `Hash`.

Instead of your current approach, you could just use `slice` to pull out the relevant key/values:

```rb
REDIS_SET_OPTIONS = %i(ex px nx xx keepttl).freeze

def set (key, value, options = nil)
  return super(key, value) unless options

  super(key, value, options.to_hash.slice(*REDIS_SET_OPTIONS))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it is really late for this issue, I run into this problem currently. And in my situation, the exception was raised due to the redis-store which was dependent by redis-rails. So when I fixed the version of the redis-rails, the exception was gone. Hope to help if you are still struggling with this issue.

```
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

.key? by convention would return a boolean. Hence your block is a no-op, as there's nothing being done with the result. What do you want to do?